# Admob does impression and click on emulator counts?

Tags: android, admob, emulation

I have an app which displays an admob banner. I have learned that a big chunk (between 500 and 1000) of my users are using my app on an emulator.

1) Does my admob account is at risk? (Some triggers google side that think I'm cheating / doing fraud)

2) If not does the impression and clicks counta 'valid'?

Comment: read admob policy for invalid clicks and activity. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

Comment: I have read it but cannot see anything about emulator (nothing that say YES or NO)

Comment: if Google identified clicks are invalid ( doesn't matter emulator or real device), they will block your account.

Comment: hmmm. what is considered a valid click/impression? Looks like you don't really know the answer and we are running in circle.

Comment: What I know is that I have not published the app version with Admob implementation and yet  I can't see any impression yet done with the IOS simulator on the admob panel